# UIButton not showing up in SKScene

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, sprite-kit

I'm trying to write some methods which can be used to generate labels, images, buttons etc.. in my spritekit project.
I call my  setUPScene method in the initWithSize method and in the setUpScene method I call three methods to set label, image and button.
My label and image appears on the main scene but I can't succeed to appear UIButton type button. Actually I seek for some error but I think everything seems right. Here are my methods;

```
-(void) setUpMainScene {

    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.15 blue:0.3 alpha:1.0];

    [self addChild:[self createLabel:@"Vecihi"
                   labelFontName:@"Chalkduster"
                   labelFontSize:20
                  labelPositionX:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)
                  labelPositionY:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)]];

   [self addChild:[self createImage:@"Spaceship"
                  imagePositionX:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)
                  imagePositionY:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)+60
                      imageWidth:40.0
                     imageHeight:60.0]];

   [self.view addSubview:[self createButton:@"ButtonSample.png"
                           setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor]
                         buttonPositionX:(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame))
                         buttonPositionY:(CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)-200.0)
                             buttonWidth:200.0
                            buttonHeight:70.0]];


}

 //Create any label with given parameters
 -(SKLabelNode *) createLabel:(NSString *) labelTitle labelFontName:(NSString *)     fontName labelFontSize:(int)fontSize labelPositionX:(CGFloat) x labelPositionY:(CGFloat) y {

    SKLabelNode *myLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:fontName];

    myLabel.text = labelTitle;
    myLabel.fontSize = fontSize;
    myLabel.position = CGPointMake(x,y);

   return myLabel;
}

 //Create any image with given parameters
-(SKSpriteNode *) createImage:(NSString *) imageName imagePositionX:(CGFloat) x   imagePositionY:(CGFloat) y imageWidth:(CGFloat) width imageHeight:(CGFloat) height {

SKSpriteNode *myImage = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:imageName];

myImage.position = CGPointMake(x, y);
myImage.size = CGSizeMake(width, height);


return myImage;

}

//Create any button wtih given parameters
-(UIButton *) createButton:(NSString *) buttonImage setTitleColor:(UIColor *) titleColor buttonPositionX:(CGFloat) x buttonPositionY:(CGFloat) y buttonWidth:(CGFloat) width buttonHeight:(CGFloat) height {

UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

NSLog(@"%@", buttonImage);

myButton.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[myButton setTitleColor:titleColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:buttonImage] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

return myButton;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to setup the button in the viewcontroller owning the scene, NOT the scene itself.

So, move

`[self.view addSubview:[self createButton:@"ButtonSample.png"
                           setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor]
                         buttonPositionX:(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame))
                         buttonPositionY:(CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)-200.0)
                             buttonWidth:200.0
                            buttonHeight:70.0]];`

in SampleScene.m

to SampleViewController.m like this

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {

    [self.view addSubview:[self.scene createButton:@"ButtonSample.png"
                       setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor]
                     buttonPositionX:(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.frame))
                     buttonPositionY:(CGRectGetMidY(self.view.frame)-200.0)
                         buttonWidth:200.0
                        buttonHeight:70.0]];

    //More commands not shown...

}
```

Please note the changes in the button positioning, and button creation

Replacing SamplesScene & SampleViewController to their corresponding names of course

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your reply. I did that, then I got an error like "no visible @interface declares ....createButton...". To solve this problem I declared this method in my scene.h class. But error is still here. How can I solve this issue? And my second question is why label and image can be added to the scene itself while button has to be added to the owner of the scene?

Comment: ok, I solved the first problem. I move my createButton method to the view controller.m. My second question is still alive.

Comment: @user3235456 you have to declare every UIView in the viewcontroller.m & it's subclasses (UIButtons, UISliders, etc.) becouse they are not so called SKNodes. However images you can create using SKSpriteNode, and labels using SKLabelNode. See the labels and images are different from normal UILabels and UIImageViews

Comment: This would just unnecessarily clutter up the viewcontroller. Also, your first statement is false - you absolutely *can* set up UI from SKScene implementations. The problem OP was having, was caused by the scene.view property not being set yet.

Comment: @JānisK thanks for the information, I didn't know that you can create & add UIViews from SKScene! However, if you're creating like an exit button, it HAS to be in the viewcontroller, since you can't push/modal viewcontrollers from skscenes

Answer (score 2):

The reason your code does not work, is because the scene's view property is set to nil, when initWithSize: is called.

You could handle this by moving the UI initialization code to the scene's [didMoveToView:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKScene/didMoveToView%3a) method. Then, in [willMoveFromView:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKScene/willMoveFromView%3a), you can perform cleanup (i.e. remove the UIButton from the view).

That way your scene-specific UI code stays in the scene, and doesn't clutter up the viewcontroller code. Especially, if you decide to add UI controls to multiple scenes - you only have one viewcontroller, and it could become messy fast.